# fast service bus for small local networks and .NET

Tags: .net, performance, servicebus

What service bus framework for .NET would you choose for small local only networks (often all participating processes even run on the same machine) if performance is an important requirement. Theoretically it must be able to handle 1000 messages per second.

Comment: requirements? does it need to queue messages if you aren't listening, for example? or basic pub/sub without queue? does it need to be persistent? transactional? free vs commercial? security requirements?

Comment: which frameworks have you considered to use? you might want to check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601518/nservicebus-vs-mass-transit-vs-rhino-service-bus-vs-other

Comment: Those are all secondary requirements and left out of this question on purpose. *Does it need to queue messages if you aren't listening?* Not necessarily. *Queue?* Not necessarily. *Persistent?* Not necessarily. *Transactional?* Not necessarily. *free vs commercial?* Both is considered though NServiceBus seem definitely too expensive. *Security requirements?* None.

Comment: You can try out (Phoenix Service Bus: http://pservicebus.codeplex.com/) It is very fast if everything is running locally and even if it running remotely. This is a sample result of how performant it is: http://pservicebus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Performance%20Result&referringTitle=Home based on this sample code: http://pservicebus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/e1c0eec063e9#pServiceBus%201.0.2%2fSamples%2fStressTest%2fStressTest%2fProgram.cs

Answer (score 0):

NServiceBus seems to be optimized for cross AppDomain calls on the same machine. There website says a lot about this.