# NServiceBus, MassTransit and Rabbit MQ or Kafka?

Tags: queue, message-queue

I am trying to learn messaging system. I have found that many options like
RabbitMq
NServiceBus
MassTransit
Kafka
...

My questions is:

What is the difference between each one?
What is the use of each?(usage scenario)

Answer (score 18):

The best way to think of NServiceBus and MassTransit is as middleware that sits on top of messaging infrastructure like RabbitMQ, Azure Service Bus, or Kafka.

For a comparison between RabbitMQ and Kafka, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42154452/151350).

For a comparison between NServiceBus and MassTransit, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647423/nservicebus-vs-masstransit/13660712#13660712).